# IP-restricted site: where to put custom 403 page in apache2.conf

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

I have an IP-restricted site configured to allow access only from specific URLs. The configuration is in apache2.conf as follows:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require ip 123.45.678.90
</Directory>
```

I'd like to display a custom 403 page instead of the default one, so I created 403.html. However, I'm having trouble finding the right place to put it in apache2.conf.

I've tried adding "ErrorDocument 403 403.html" inside the  directive, but then the webpage literally displays "403.html" -- not the page, but that actual string. That'd be fine if I just wanted to have the message IN the apache2.conf, but I'd prefer to actually have a page I can edit a little more conveniently.

I've tried placing it outside the Directory directive, but that returns the typical 403, plus the following:

> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I figure that makes sense, since they're not allowed in that directory anyway. So, I tried creating a new folder called /var/error and adding it there. However, that returns the same "additionally..." error above.

Where's the proper place (and how) to put this?

Comment: Would also love an answer for this!